# Why doesn't the chatroom have any smiley?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Why doesn't the chatroom have any smiley? It can help us to transfer the emotions. I know that here isn't suitable for chatting but IMO having the smileys is a good idea.

Comment: Side matter: I understand you're not a native speaker, I'm also not. But I feel we can put an extra effort in checking for grammar errors and typos, for the benefit of readability. The other users (and readers especially) will be grateful.

Comment: @clabacchio Oh, sometimes I'm Careless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because we are serious people :) (look, an emoticon!)

Jokes aside, I don't really see it as a priority, and most of the people around here are probably more pleased with the plain text emoticons. Or at least this is my impression.

Anyway, I think the proper place to ask is the [Stack Exchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). Where, I just noticed, the issue has been raised with [not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234840/emoticons-for-stack-exchange-chat) [so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77958/emoticons-am-i-the-first) [much](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/636/should-smilies-be-turned-into-images-in-questions-and-answers) [success](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137532/textual-smilies-emoticons-usage/137570#137570), I fear.

Comment: LoL! I wish that we had emoticon.

Comment: +1 for standard emoticons, instead of horrible mini-graphics or whatever was being proposed.

Comment: @JYelton and also -1 to me! lol

Comment: @roh In meta, a downvote just means I disagree; it doesn't affect your reputation as it would on the main site.

Comment: @JYelton Yeah, I know.